# Separate DataBase Entity Layer and Data Access Layer in c#?

Tags: c#, connection-string, data-access-layer, 3-tier

I want to separate DB entity layer from DataAccessLayer.

i'll write my steps:

1. Create empty solution 'DB_sep'
2. create class library 'DB'
3. Add ADO.NET Entity Data Model 'DBEntity' of my Database to 'DB' project
4. Add console application 'App' to 'DB_sep'
5. Add 'DB' reference to  'App' project

Now I would like to access DB objects from 'App' project , but I can't access dbContext, I'm getting Error

'No connection string named 'DBEntity' could be found in the application config file.'

I've got this lines of code:

```
try
{
DB.DBEntity db = new DB.DBEntity();
Customer cust = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == 2);
Console.WriteLine(cust.Name);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Is there a way to keep connection string only in 'DB' or I must put it in 'App' project?

Comment: just curious why are you declring an object two times

Comment: it was my mistake pasted it two times i've already edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'No connection string named 'DBEntity' could be found in the application config file.' - seems legit enough.

Add an `app.config` file (e.g. with the appropriate [ConnectionString declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to the *project that actually executes*.

Since targeting EF, pay attention to the specific [Entity Framework Configuration Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606) - i.e. here it is looking for the name `DBEntity`. The actual rules vary depending on exactly *which* version of EF is used. (The chances are pretty good that there is an `app.config` in the model project which can be used as a reference.)

---

It is also possible to specify a DbConnection (or perhaps connection string) to the appropriate constructor overload - i.e. via *dependency injection* - or otherwise specify an alternate database provider.

Comment: i'm using EF and my connection string is in 'DB' project `app.config` file, the main thing for me is not to put connection string in 'App' project settings

Comment: @DatoJanez The Connection String (or other configuration approach) must be specified in the `app.config` *of the executing project/assembly* as well - in this case that is the console application (not the DB project). If you absolutely cannot (or will not) put the the connection string in `app.config` of the console application, then see one of the other approaches - e.g. create a database factory in the model (specified through the app.config configuration) or create a DbConnection via another means and pass it to the context constructor (perhaps loaded via dependency injection).

Comment: this is just my test case for separating WCF (Data Access Layer) from DB layer, I'm going to change console application with WCF. Should I put my connection string in WCF project? I would be thankful if you can help.

Comment: @DatoJanez If you have a WCF (or other Web) project, then the settings go in the `web.config` file which is merged into the IIS config (it's very similar to the role of `app.config`, which is for executable assemblies). Confusing, ehh? Basically, each *executing assembly* needs to have access to the configuration to create the appropriate connection (and each configuration can be different).

Comment: OK it means that i should put my connection string in DAL application `web/app.config` file

Comment: @DatoJanez Close .. in the `web.config` for the WCF/Web project. In the `app.config` for the console application project. The `web|app.config` in the DAL ("DB") project is *not used* by default as it is not the executing assembly.